# Difference between id and equality in python

Tags: python

How is the `id` of an object computed? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

It seems there is a place in a class to do equality, with `__eq__` but where is the `is` operation done, and how is the `id` arrived at?

Comment: Are you asking this because you want to modify how `is` operates? When an object is created in python, it is assigned an ID value by the interpreter. This ID is guaranteed to be unique throughout the lifetime of the individual program being run and as long as the object exists. Access to how this ID is set is not available to the programmer (I'm sure there IS a way through super hacky stuff but probably requires re-compiling the interpreter). The behavior of `a is b` can't be modified

Comment: The python data model provides no hooks for customizing the semantics of the `is` operator. It seems like a bad idea. `is` is always for object identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is the `id` of an object computed? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

You don't know. This is what [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) has to say:

> ## `id`(*object*)
>
> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.

That is all the guarantees that Python makes about `id()`:

- it returns an `int`
- no two objects can have the same `id()` at the same time
- no object can have two different `id()`s

And that is *all* the guarantees that Python makes. In particular, the documentation explicitly points out one guarantee that it *doesn't* make:

- `id()`s are not globally unique in space and time, i.e. two different objects may have the same `id()` at different times

You will also notice that the documentation makes no guarantees about how the `id()` is computed.

It *does*, however, say this:

> **CPython implementation detail**: This is the address of the object in memory.

This actually *re-inforces* the fact there are no guarantees about how `id()`s are computed by explicitly stating that this

- *only* applies to CPython and not any other implementation such as PyPy, Jython, IronPython, GraalPython, or PythonOMR
- is an *implementation detail*, meaning that it can be changed at any time, for any reason, without warning

In fact, it is actually *impossible* for any implementation other than CPython to implement `id()` this way, since all other implementations have either moving garbage collectors (PyPy, PythonOMR), or don't even have a concept of "memory address" at all (Jython, IronPython, GraalPython).

> It seems there is a place in a class to do equality, with `__eq__` but where is the `is` operation done, and how is the `id` arrived at?

Let me break that down into two answers:

> where is the `is` operation done

It is defined as part of the Python Language Specification, just like, say `def`. It does not translate into a method call, there is no way to modify its behavior.

> how is the `id` arrived at

You don't know, can't know, and mustn't know. All you know is that it is an identifier, the *actual value* is opaque.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of `id(obj)` as some sort of address of the object.
The way it is computed, and what the value represents, is implementation-dependent, and you should not make any assumptions about the value.

What you need to know:

1. Object's `id` will not change as long as the object exists
2. Two co-existing objects will have different `id`s
3. An object may have the same `id` as another object which has already been deallocated (since it is gone, its address may be reused).
4. `a is b` is equivalent to `id(a) == id(b)`.

You cannot override the way `id` is computed, nor the way `is` behaves, like you'd override operators such as `__eq__`.

Answer (score 1):

From the page you have provided URL for: "CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory." -- so `id` is basically an address, not more not less.